# Pitch recognition games in the browser

Tags: audio, browser, pitch-tracking

I'd really like to develop some games and exercises that run in the browser and use pitch detection to listen with the microphone and award points for correct answers.

Is this in the realms of fantasy?  If not, what is the starting point?